# How can I make my computer without an X-server stop booting into TTY 7 and boot directly into TTY 1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty

I recently disabled the graphical login manager on my Ubuntu and started using **startx**. But when the computer turns on, instead of giving me a login prompt in one of the TTYs (I think that's how you call the terminals in Ctr+Alt+F1 and so on), it shows the display where X runs (the Ctrl+Alt+F7 one), and so I have to switch back to another one to be able to login.

It is only a minor annoyance, but does anyone know how I can make it boot directly into the first TTY?

Comment: Did you update `/etc/inittab` to disable the graphical login manager, or something else?

Comment: I just uninstalled it. I don't have that file in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836985), this is a bug in the install CD.  To fix it and change your default `tty` from `tty7` to `tty1`, you need to edit the GRUB configuration file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`.

In this file, find the location where the `vt_handoff` variable is set, and modify the value to `1` instead of `7` (you should see something like `set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7` already).  Note you will need root to do this so you'll need to edit it with `sudo`.

Once this is done, update GRUB with the new configuration (`sudo update-grub`), and reboot.